# rails show page works in development but not in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone know why could a `show` page on rails works locally but on staging get the `This page does not exist` message? I am having issues only with the business show route. I am 100% sure the IDs I am passing are correct

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Resque::Server.new, at: "/resque"

  resources :user_shares
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions",
    registrations: "users/registrations",
    passwords: "users/passwords",
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"
  }
  use_doorkeeper

  root 'welcome#index'


  resources :user_profiles do
    post :upload_image, on: :member
    get :change_password, on: :member
    put :update_password, on: :member
  end

  resources :calendar, only: :index do
    get :events_for_day, on: :collection
    post :attend_event, on: :collection
  end

  resources :organizations, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :leaderboard, only: :index
    resources :progress_chart, only: :index
    resources :live_action_feed, only: :index
    resources :actions do
      get :events, on: :collection
    end
    resources :user_actions
    resources :share, only: :create
  end


  namespace :admin do
    resources :organizations do
      put :remove_user, on: :member
      resources :actions
      resources :action_suggestions
      resources :action_templates
      resources :users do
        resources :user_actions
      end
      resources :activates do
        post :import, on: :collection
      end
      resources :notifications
      resources :engagement
      resources :action_uptake
      resources :administration

    end
  end

  namespace :system_admin do
    resources :organizations
    resources :locations
    resources :action_templates do
      post :feature, on: :member
      delete :unfeature, on: :member
    end
    resources :action_suggestions do
      get :reject, on: :member
    end
  end

  resources :check_ins, only: :create
  resources :social_feed
  resources :user_action_likes
  resources :user_roles
  resources :activates
  resources :twitter
  resources :device, only: :create
  resources :authorizations, only: :destroy
  resources :organization_profiles, only: :show
  resources :businesses do
    delete :delete_review, on: :member
  end

  match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: [:get, :post] unless Rails.env.development?
end
```

This is the `environments/staging.rb`:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # include all helpers
  config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = true

  config.after_initialize do
    ActionMailer::Base.asset_host = APP_CONFIG['asset_host']
    ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = {host: APP_CONFIG['smtp_default_host']}
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
        domain: APP_CONFIG['smtp_domain'],
        address: APP_CONFIG['smtp_address'],
        port: APP_CONFIG['smtp_port'],
        enable_starttls_auto: true,
        authentication: :login,
        user_name: APP_CONFIG['smtp_username'],
        password: APP_CONFIG['smtp_password']
    }
  end

  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Graylog2.new
  config.logger = GELF::Logger.new('logs.sparknettech.com', 12201, 'WAN', {:facility => "milkcrate-rails-staging"})

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `rake routes` on the staging env machine. This will print out all the registered routes in the console. Letting you be certain the change was deployed and the route actually exists in the staging env.

You might also want to restart the server/app just to be sure changes the configuration files were picked up.

Posting the route will also be helpful. If the route syntax itself is the problem.

Comment: I did this and confirmed the route is in fact there. That is the weirdest part.